# ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified on a leap year with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, jdbc

I'm inserting data into my oracle sql database and one of the values is a date from 1980 february 29th. When I'm adding this value, I'm getting this error

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.generateBatchUpdateException(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10891)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatchWithoutQueue(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10311)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10016)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeBatch(OracleStatement.java:5420)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:289)
```

The solution I've seen is using `add_months` but I couldn't apply it with the PreparedStatements from jdbc. How can I do it? This is the code I'm using with prepared statements

```
  String personneString = "INSERT INTO personne (idPersonne, datedenaissance) VALUES (?, ?)";

  Date annivDate = (anniv == null) ? null : Date.valueOf(anniv);

  try (PreparedStatement statementPersonne = connection.prepareStatement(personneString)) {
     statementPersonne.setInt(1, idPersonne);
     statementPersonne.setDate(2,  annivDate);
     statementPersonne.addBatch();
     statementPersonne.executeBatch();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
     System.out.println("date = " + annivDate);
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Which prints `date = 1980-02-29`

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem in Oracle [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MnKQnXgp). Please [edit] the question and include a complete [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the `personne` table; details of any triggers on the table (or fast-refresh materialized views); and the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` that your session is using.

Comment: @BasilBourque it's of type Date and the version is `12.2.0.1.0` enterprise edition

Comment: Post such details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.